# What are the template parameters of std::priority_queue?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, priority-queue

I was looking through some STL documentation. I see that the syntax for a priority queue which stores in a descending order is:

```
std::priority_queue<int> q ;
//gives 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  when pushed and obtained
```

However, for storing in an ascending fashion, it's:

```
std::priority_queue< int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q ;
//gives 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 when pushed and obtained
```

I want to know what are the specific uses of the extra template parameters  in the second example.  As in, what does `std::vector<int>` do in that example?

Also, can someone could further explain this declaration?

```
priority_queue< pair<int ,int > , vector< pair<int ,int > > , greater< pair<int ,int > > > q ;
```

Comment: In C++, you cannot set 3rd parameter without setting the previous ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is not a container in itself, it's a *container adaptor*, which means it uses another container internally to store the actual data in the queue.

By default it uses a `std::vector` of the type stored in the queue.

The problem here is that just like passing arguments to a function with default arguments, you can't skip arguments in the template list even if they have default types, you must always provide the previous template arguments.

If you see the linked reference you will see that the second and third template arguments to `std::priority_queue` have default types. If you want to change the third template argument you must also provide the second template argument as well, which is the actual underlying container. So for a `std::priority_queue` of `int`, you need to provide `std::vector<int>`.

---

<strike>There are however a way to not pass the type of the comparator as a template argument, the [`std::priority_queue` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) also takes an (optional) argument for the comparator function. Here you can provide any function, function object, lambda or other callable object.</strike>

In your case you could do e.g.

```
std::priority_queue<int> q{std::greater<int>()};
```

The above declaration creates a `std::greater<int>` object and passes it as comparator to the `std::priority_queue` constructor.

Comment: Why isn't vector required to be specified in the first example then !?

Comment: @saru95 Because it have a default type, please see the linked reference.

Comment: So, are you saying in that in the first case vector is being used by default but in the second case due to `greater` we have to explicitly specify it ?

Comment: @saru95 That's correct. There are however another way of passing the comparator to use, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ohkk ! I get it . Thanks.

Comment: Downvoting, because: 1) `std::priority_queue<int> q(std::greater<int>());` will be parsed as a function pointer declaration, not an object constructor 2) std::priority_queue **does not have** a constructor you are taking about; it only accepts a comparator of type `Compare`, which defaults to `std::less<T>`. You have to specify a different comparator type as a template argument to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

std::priority_queue is a container which wraps another container, meaning that it only provide `priority` and `queue` abstraction on top of another container, as long this one match the `SequenceContainer` [concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer).

A user may change containers if it want different time and memory complexity constraint. Or provide its own container.

the `std::greater<T>` is a comparator on elements of type `T`. It is required to satisfy total ordering.